# How was onClick(View v) Automatically executed?

Tags: java, android

Hi im a begginer on Android development. I knew basic core java. So i have a question on this particular code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{ 
    @Override public void onClick(View v) 
    {    
        // do something when the button is clicked 
    } 
});
```

I know that this is anonymous class and OnClickListener is an interface. But what i dont understand is the onClick(View v) method, v is the button that was clicked but under the hood how was this method AUTOMATICALLY executed? I mean isnt that to be able to call a method you must first create an object then a method beside it? I just need to understand this concept, thank you.

Comment: `button` is the object, which previously you have initialized with `findViewById()` and for that you explicitly define a listener. This listener is *attached* to this object as long as it exists.

Comment: You're actually creating the `OnClickListener` object anonymously within the method `button.setOnClickListener` with `new` operator. You could have also done it like `View.OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener() { /* methods */ };` and then set it to `button.setOnClickListener(myListener)`. Learn more on anonymous class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 2):

In simple words when you create a Button object it has some listener objects:

Example:

```
class Button extends View{
   private OnClickListener clickListener;

   public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener clickListener){
          this.clickListener = clickListener;
   }
}
```

when you call this:

```
button.setOnClickListener();
```

basically you assign the value to clickListener in Button class and then each time you click the button it triggers

`clickListener.onClick(this)`

and perform your defined stuff.

Comment: Hope you get some idea.

Comment: this is actually very much helpful

Answer (score 1):

Your listener is provided to the `Button` object, and by clicking the button, the Android framework will try to invoke the `OnClickListener` (if any) by calling the `onClick` method you provide.

So it is not really automatically. Your action triggers the click, and Android framework calls your `onClick`.

Comment: thanks for that answer, i think i should go ahead and learn more about android framework ;)